# File being served from FileProvider isn't showing up as full resolution in older Samsung Gallery

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

I have noticed this on Samsung device running older versions of Android (SM-T231 Running 4.4.2 and GT-I9500 running 5.0.1).

When a file is served through our app's [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) it works as expected, but when zooming in, the built in Gallery app doesn't seem to load more pixels. It then looks much more low res than the image actually is.

Using the debugger, I can see our app's content provider gets hit with a query to determine the filename and size of the file (in bytes) being opened as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#query). Same for the mime type. The correct values are returned in both cases.

Viewing the same file (using the Gallery app) from the SD card works as expected. All the pixels are shown when zooming.

Using Google Photos app to view the image from the content provider (or the filesystem), works as expected on these devices.

Viewing the file on an Android 5 device but with a larger screen (8" SM-T705) seems to work fine when zooming.  Guess the display resolution or density might make a difference as well?  (Both this device and the GT-I9500 has version 5.0.1 of the Samsung Gallery)

Is there any way I can get the built in Gallery app to load the full resolution image?

Below images are taken as screenshots from Gallery app on the SM-T231, zoomed in on the same part of the image.  As you can see, the one from the FileProvider is much blurrier than the one from the filesystem.

[image: Zoomed in when viewing through content provider - blurry]
[image: Zoomed in when viewing through filesystem - not so blurry]

Comment: That does not look to me as if it has anything to do with your file provider. Your provider can only serve that file. Blame the app that uses the file.

Comment: What I find annoying though is that the same app does a very different thing depending on the context.

Comment: Offer the app its own content scheme/uri you picked with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: All the `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does is show up the image picker view of the built in gallery.  I would rather have the built in gallery just show the image correctly.  This is will with a URI of `content://appname.etc.etc`

Comment: Yes then you can pick an image from the gallery. After that use the obtained uri as it it was yours to let the gallery zoom in on that. Thats what i suggested. A test.